# Volumes and VOLUME: Does a path have to exist in both places?

Tags: linux, share, docker, disk-volume

If I'm going to run nginx like so:

```
docker run -i -t -p 80:80 \
-v /docker/dev:/dev \
-v /docker/var/www:/var/www \
-v /docker/var/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx \
-v /docker/etc/nginx:/etc/nginx \
--name clmnginxbash quasaur/nginximage /bin/bash
```

...and I'm using the Docker HOST's filesystem to store `nginx`'s configs and the website itself, I shouldn't have to include a VOLUME statement for those shares, or should I?

```
VOLUME ["/etc/nginx", "/var/www","/var/log/nginx"]
```

In fact, shouldn't I be able to remove those directories from the image in the Dockerfile since they're not going to be used?

```
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/www /etc/nginx /var/log/nginx
```

Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying `-v` at run or volumes in the `VOLUME` instruction both mount a volume that bypasses UFS to store persistent data. See https://docs.docker.com/terms/layer/#ufs-def. It is an actual mount in the container:

```
$ docker run --rm ubuntu mount | grep mnt
```

Nothing mounted in the container. Let's try that again with a `-v /mnt`:

```
$ docker run --name mount -v /mnt ubuntu mount | grep mnt
/dev/sda1 on /mnt type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

Cool, we have a persistent mount. But we didn't specify a place on the host to store it... where does it actually live?

```
$ docker inspect --format '{{ .Volumes }}' mount
map[/mnt:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/3d0eff68f9db4821821812f9e363c1e6058105de8a7a04ecfda113e8def9848a]
```

As you have pointed out already, you can map this mount to a directory on the host by prefixing it with something:

```
$ docker run --rm -v /folder/on/host:/mnt
```

So, to answer your two questions, no, the VOLUME instructions in the `Dockerfile` are not required. Should you remove them? I guess, assuming you will never have persistent data in the containers without specifying `-v`.

Comment: Thank you for your timely feedback! Another question: how does Docker handle rights on the Docker HOST when it shares its file system with the Docker container (i'm thinking about an Nginx container's expectation of, say, /var/www on the Docker HOST having permissions for user www-data)??

Comment: It is going assume the user ID of the user in the container. If you have a user www with ID 1000 in the container and user docker with id 1000 on the host, when www writes a file to that mapped host directory, it will appear as owned by docker on the host.